# Why Selenium Python script freeze on EC2?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run a script, but when I ran the process freeze. Here is the code

```
def get_source_content(url):

  driver_path = f"{settings.BASE_DIR}/geckodriver"
  options = FirefoxOptions()
  options.add_argument("--headless")
  options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
  options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
  options.add_argument("--single-process")
  options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(executable_path=driver_path), options=options)

  try:
    driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
    element = driver.find_element(
        "xpath", "//button[@class='sc-beySPh gNAvzR mde-consent-accept-btn']"
    )
    element.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
    source = driver.page_source

  except Exception as ex:
    raise ex

  driver.quit()
  return source
```

The code only freeze deployed on AWS EC2, locally works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

The problem was related to the display, so adding this extra options arguments:

```
options.add_argument("--window-size=800,600")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--enable-automation")
```

and use a third party library to simulate fake display the problem was fixed

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
...
display.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is your use of WebDriverWait. It is not supposed to be used like this (this way it literally does nothing). The general use is WebDriverWait(driver, amount).until(expected_conditions.some_condition(webelement))

In your case:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='sc-beySPh gNAvzR mde-consent-accept-btn']")))
```

Comment: Checked locally with initial code works perfectly